# Angular 6 - UI freezes after error occurs

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http

A service sends a http request using `HttpClient` core angular service like:

```
return this.httpService.get<MyObj[]>(myURL).pipe(catchError(errorHandle));
```

*errorHandle: passed as a property to the function calling `.get()`*

I send a 400 Bad Request from my nodejs server which is picked up by the following errorHandle:

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.isLoading = false;
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      this.error = error.error.message;
    } else {
      this.error = "Backend server error, status code:" + error.status
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened');
}
```

Now, `this.isLoading` is used in UI to prevent a div from rendering and instead show 'Loading...'. When I set it to false in the `handleError` it does update the property, but it doesnt affect the UI. It keeps *Loading...*.

Code for reference:

**Component:**

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.isLoading = false;
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      this.error = error.error.message;
    } else {
      this.error = "Backend server error, status code:" + error.status
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened');
}

ngOnInit() {
    //returns 400 Bad Request
 this.variablesService.getVariables(URL.MODELVARIABLE+','+URL.METRICVARIABLE, this.handleError).subscribe(variables => {
      this.fetchedVariables = variables.map(variable => new Variable(variable));
      this.variables = this.fetchedVariables.filter(variable => variable.isglobal);
      this.populateGridItems(GRIDNAME.GlobalVariable, this.variables);
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

**UI:**

```
<error [error]="error"></error> <!-- content which should show as ive set this.error but still doesnt -->
<div *ngIf="!isLoading && !error">
...content that doesnt show which is fine
</div>
<p *ngIf="isLoading">Loading..</p> <!-- keeps showing even when ive set it to false -->
```

Comment: Are you sure your `errorHandle` function is called? You could add a `console.log(...)` to check.

Comment: @Ploppy yes i checked. I logged to see if this.isLoading is getting updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you "handle" the error but then you rethrow it and never handle the rethrown error, and an unhandled error breaks an observable stream. You have 2 options:

don't rethrow the error

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.isLoading = false;
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      this.error = error.error.message;
    } else {
      this.error = "Backend server error, status code:" + error.status
    }
    return empty();
}
```

or handle the rethrown error in the second argument to subscribe:

```
this.variablesService.getVariables(URL.MODELVARIABLE+','+URL.METRICVARIABLE, this.handleError).subscribe(variables => {
  this.fetchedVariables = variables.map(variable => new Variable(variable));
  this.variables = this.fetchedVariables.filter(variable => variable.isglobal);
  this.populateGridItems(GRIDNAME.GlobalVariable, this.variables);
  this.isLoading = false;
},
(error) => console.log(error, "do whatever you want here"));
```

Comment: Can only accept after 8 minutes! Thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: So just to clear myself up a bit more, `.pipe()` is like a middle part between result and request?

Comment: pipe is like defining a set of steps to take on an observable stream of data.  Your http request is an observable stream, pipe defines a set of operations to take on that stream.  In this case, the operation is handling errors. But if you throw a new error in your handler and don't handle that new error, then nothing catches it since it occurred after your error handling step in your pipe.

Comment: Very well explained! Thanks.